# Python Sorting nested list of student lessons

Tags: python, list, sorting, nested

I am new to python and I have difficulty finishing this code. Having the data_list and the given code, how can I make a code that creates a nested list of each subject, how many people attend, grade average of this subject? The output should look like this:

```
[["Physics", 3, 6.0], ["PC", 4, 8.25], ....]
```

This is what I have done with some help

```
data_list =
 ["John", "Physics", 5], ["John", "PC", 7], ["John", "Math", 8], 
 ["Mary", "Physics", 6], ["Mary", "PC", 10], ["Mary", "Algebra", 7], 
 ["Helen", "Physics", 7], ["Helen","PC", 6], ["Helen", "Algebra", 8], 
 ["Helen", "Analysis", 10], ["Bill", "PC", 10], ["Bill", "Analysis", 6], 
 ["Bill", "Math", 8], ["Bill", "Biology", 6], ["Michael", "Analysis", 10]
]

def groupby(data, index, category):
    """Sort list of records by index and category
    """
    output = []
    indices = []
    for record in data:
        if record[index] not in indices:
            indices.append(record[index])
            output.append([record[index]])
            output[-1].append(record[category])
        else:
            output[indices.index(record[index])].append(record[category])
    return output

# index 0 -> person
# category 1 -> subject
subject_list = groupby(data_list, 0, 1)

# index 0 -> person
# category 2 -> grade
grade_list = groupby(data_list, 0, 2)

# grad_list
[['John', 5, 7, 8],
 ['Mary', 6, 10, 7],
 ['Helen', 7, 6, 8, 10],
 ['Bill', 10, 6, 8, 6],
 ['Michael', 10]]
```

You can then get the number of subjects taken per person or the average grade like this:

```
import statistics

subjects_taken = [len(x) - 1 for x in subject_list]
average_grade = [statistics.mean(x[1:]) for x in grade_list]
```

Putting everything together gives you:

```
persons = [x[0] for x in subject_list]
final_list = list(zip(persons, subjects_taken, average_grade))

# final_list
[('John', 3, 6.666666666666667),
 ('Mary', 3, 7.666666666666667),
 ('Helen', 4, 7.75),
 ('Bill', 4, 7.5),
 ('Michael', 1, 10)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group `data_list` by subject:

```
from pprint import pprint
from statistics import mean
from itertools import groupby


data_list = [
 ["John", "Physics", 5], ["John", "PC", 7], ["John", "Math", 8],
 ["Mary", "Physics", 6], ["Mary", "PC", 10], ["Mary", "Algebra", 7],
 ["Helen", "Physics", 7], ["Helen","PC", 6], ["Helen", "Algebra", 8],
 ["Helen", "Analysis", 10], ["Bill", "PC", 10], ["Bill", "Analysis", 6],
 ["Bill", "Math", 8], ["Bill", "Biology", 6], ["Michael", "Analysis", 10]
]

out = []
for k, g in groupby(sorted(data_list, key=lambda k: k[1]), lambda k: k[1]):
    g = [*g]
    out.append([k, len(g), mean(v[2] for v in g)])

pprint(out)
```

Prints:

```
[['Algebra', 2, 7.5],
 ['Analysis', 3, 8.666666666666666],
 ['Biology', 1, 6],
 ['Math', 2, 8],
 ['PC', 4, 8.25],
 ['Physics', 3, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily with Pandas. You can take a look in their documentation for further explanation about the syntax, but here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd

data_list = [

 ["John", "Physics", 5], ["John", "PC", 7], ["John", "Math", 8], 
 ["Mary", "Physics", 6], ["Mary", "PC", 10], ["Mary", "Algebra", 7], 
 ["Helen", "Physics", 7], ["Helen","PC", 6], ["Helen", "Algebra", 8], 
 ["Helen", "Analysis", 10], ["Bill", "PC", 10], ["Bill", "Analysis", 6], 
 ["Bill", "Math", 8], ["Bill", "Biology", 6], ["Michael", "Analysis", 10]
]

# Convert the data_list array into a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data_list, columns=['Name', 'Subject', 'Grade'])

# Group by Subject extracting the count and mean of the accumulated grade per subject
df.groupby('Subject').Grade.agg(['count', 'mean'])
```

And here's the result:

[image]